# Change language programmatically using 'Locale' working on only MainActivity. How to change language in all activities

Tags: java, android, locale

Possible duplicate, but didn't find proper answer anywhere.
Using multiple tutorials any code copy/paste  I success in changing the language of app, but it's only working in MainActivity which read strings from string.xml(hi).But When I switch the activity using Intent the second activity has default strings.xml. I tried myself to do some changes in second activity but it is causing app crash when called from first activity (i can rewind it but still attached the code to show error).
please Help! How I can change the language of all activities, Attaching all code I have used. Also please go through my codes if there is any bad coding help me to resolve them.
and sorry for the bad grammar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARm7s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X33ay.png)

### **LocaleHelper.Java**

```
package com.example.kymform;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    // the method is used to set the language at runtime
    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        // updating the language for devices above android nougat
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        // for devices having lower version of android os
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    // the method is used update the language of application by creating
    // object of inbuilt Locale class and passing language argument to it
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.kymform;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //-----for language-----
    Spinner languageSpinner;
    Locale myLocale;
    static String currentLanguage = "en", currentLang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //TOOLBAR HIDE
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        languageSpinner = findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);
        currentLanguage = getIntent().getStringExtra(currentLang);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Select language");
        list.add("English");
        list.add("Hindi");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        languageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //=============Language change on selected from spinner=============
        languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setLocale("en");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setLocale("hi");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    //======LANGUAGE CHANGE METHOD========================
    public void setLocale(String localeName) {
        if (!localeName.equals(currentLanguage)) {
            Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, localeName);
            //Resources resources = context.getResources();
            myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale; //API<24
            //conf.setLocale(myLocale); //API>=24
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
            startActivity(refresh);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Language already selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
    }

    //======ADD NEW FARMER BUTTON===================
    public void addFarmer(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FarmerDetailsActivity.class));
    }

    //======LOGOUT BUTTON===================
    public void logoutUser(View view) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        Toast.makeText(this, "User Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

**FarmerDetails.Java**

```
package com.example.kymform;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

public class FarmerDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Locale myLocale;
    String currentLanguage = "en";

    TextView farmerNameBar;
    TextView farmerVillageBar;
    EditText fpoNameEditText;
    EditText memberIdEditText;
    EditText memberFirstNameEditText;
    EditText memberLastNameEditText;
    EditText memberContactNumberEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farmer_details);

        //TOOLBAR HIDE
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        currentLanguage = MainActivity.currentLanguage;
        setLocale(currentLanguage);

        farmerNameBar = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.farmerNameBar );
        farmerVillageBar = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.farmerVillageBar );
        fpoNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.fpoNameEditText );
        memberIdEditText = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.memberIdEditText );
        memberFirstNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.memberFirstNameEditText );
        memberLastNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.memberLastNameEditText );
        memberContactNumberEditText = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.memberContactNumberEditText );

    }

    //======LANGUAGE CHANGE METHOD========================
    public void setLocale(String localeName) {
            Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, localeName);
            //Resources resources = context.getResources();
            myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale; //API<24
            //conf.setLocale(myLocale); //API>=24
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, FarmerDetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
    }

    //============HOME BUTTON ACTION=================
    public void homePage(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.alert_message))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(this.getString(R.string.positive_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(this.getString(R.string.negative_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    //=================MOVE TO NEXT ACTIVITY===================
    public void nextPage(View view) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CropDetailsActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    //==============SAVE DETAILS IN FIREBASE==================
    public void saveDetails(View view) {
        //firebase code
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //========IF USER PRESSED BACK BUTTON OF DEVICE===========
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        homePage(null);
    }

}
```

**Crash Logcat**

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2021-03-07 23:07:15.469 25288-25288/com.example.kymform E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kymform, PID: 25288
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kymform/com.example.kymform.FarmerDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Locale.java:737)
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Locale.java:790)
        at com.example.kymform.LocaleHelper.updateResources(LocaleHelper.java:61)
        at com.example.kymform.LocaleHelper.setLocale(LocaleHelper.java:37)
        at com.example.kymform.FarmerDetailsActivity.setLocale(FarmerDetailsActivity.java:113)
        at com.example.kymform.FarmerDetailsActivity.onCreate(FarmerDetailsActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7824)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7813)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: your question doesn't have anything to do with android studio particularly, but everything else in your question seems fine, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Start reading in the ActivityThread.java class line 3270, It seems to try and read something and returns "null" so it is probably trying to read a a variable empty at runtime.